# Обобщенный метод выбрасывет исключение

Tags: c#

Написал обобщенный метод сортировки.При проверке на `ar3` выбрасывет исключение "обьекты должны быть типа int"

```
   struct myStrct:IComparable
    {
        public int d;
        public myStrct(int i)
        {
            d = i;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return d.CompareTo(obj);
        }
    }
    public static T[] soRt<T>(T[] A) where T : IComparable
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (A[j].CompareTo(A[j + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    T temp = A[j];
                    A[j] = A[j + 1];
                    A[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ar1 = new int[] { 4, 2, -1, 0, 3, 13 };
        soRt(ar1);
        foreach (var a in ar1)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine();
        string[] ar2 = new string[] { "ethh", "tjyuk", "ethrtyhrhh", "dfgvbdgh", "scas", "zcvfb", };
        soRt(ar2);
        foreach (var a in ar2)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine();
        myStrct[] ar3 = new myStrct[] { new myStrct(2), new myStrct(0), new myStrct(21), new myStrct(5), new myStrct(3), new myStrct(1) };
        soRt(ar3);
        foreach (var a in ar3)
            Console.WriteLine(a.d);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: "выбрасывет исключение" - какая строчка?

Comment: `if (A[j].CompareTo(A[j + 1]) > 0)` когда вызывается `soRt(ar3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` не может сравнить себя с `myStrct`:

```
struct myStrct:IComparable
{
    public int d;
    public myStrct(int i)
    {
        d = i;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return d.CompareTo(((myStrct)obj).d); // !!!
    }
}
```